# ASP.NET Memory Leak - OracleConnection/OracleCommand

Tags: asp.net, windbg

I have followed the advice in the following tutorial: http://humblecoder.co.uk/tag/windbg.  I have got to he point that says, run this command: !dumpheap.  I have added he total number of bytes in the third column and divided it by 1024 and 1024 again.  This equates to 42MB.  The ASP.NET process in question is over 1.5GB in size.

This is done on a Windows 2003 server were there is no option to create a dump file in Task Manager.  Therefore I have to run the following cmmand: .dump /ma w3wpdump.dmp.  As this is a mini dump, is there stuff that is missing that could help?

I did ask another question about this yesterday, which outlines the problem: [ASP.NET Memory Leak - OracleCommand Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506807/asp-net-memory-leak-oraclecommand-object)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your other question is appears that the vast majority of your memory usage is being used by strings. I would dump some of those strings to see what is inside of them. You can view the contents of the string using `dd` or `db` or `du` and giving it the memory address of one of the instances of the strings. i.e. `dd 0x12345678` and it will dump the raw contents of the memory located there. You can look at the windbg help to get more information on the `d*` commands.

But if you're sure the managed heap doesn't appear to be consuming the memory then I would look at the unmanaged heap. `!heap -s` will give you a summary of the unmanaged heaps, which might be where you have excess memory usage.

Comment: Thanks.  There are a lot of Strings that are concatenated together.  I know that I should be using the StringBuilder object.  My previous post suggests that there is 19472876 bytes allocated to Strings - this is jut 18MB.  Would you say this is quite a lot.  18MB does not seem much to me.  Are there unmanaged resources used when you create/use a String?

Comment: Sorry misread the amounts when I first looked at them. In this case I would check the unmanged heap.

Comment: Do you think there are a lot of strings? I don't really have anything to compare it to.

Comment: ~56,000 isn't a huge number, but it's not tiny either. There aren't really any guidelines on how many strings you should see since each programs usage will be different.

Comment: Do you think it could be the OracleConnection and OracleCommand objects that are causing the leak?

Comment: Probably not, why would you think they are causing the leak?

Comment: Because there is more memory allocated to those objects than any other - except Strings.